# C++ Classes without class body declared outside of the namespace

Tags: c++, class, templates, namespaces

I'm really new to C++ Programming and I'm trying to teach it myself. While I was having a look at some code I noticed the following:

```
#ifndef _someclass_h_
#define _someclass_h_

class A;
class B;
class C;

namespace somenamespace{

class SomeClass 
{
public: 

...
};
}
```

I'm confused about the classes A, B and C being declared outside of the namespace while not having any class body. What is done here? 
Does it have something to do with templates?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search Keyword: "Forward Declaration".

Answer (score 0):

These are forward declarations. C++ programmers use forward declarations to avoid having to include the header file for a class definition.

The classes A, B, and C are declared in the global namespace.